# Having a problem validating email address in PHP with preg_match

Tags: php, email, preg-match, validation

Here's the code:

```
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }
```

Here's the error msg:

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '/' found in /home/bigsilkd/public_html/UBA/join.php on line 22

Comment: The problem is that you're not using the correct regex for validating email addresses. The correct one can be found here: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);` was to complicated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's exactly what it says:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"
```

should be

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/"
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                                  This was missing ---/
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use regular expressions for validating emails. For example your regex wouldn't allow my email address `+@example.org`, which is a normal and valid email. Save my email! It's dying out, because of bad form validation! Use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var)!

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // email is valid
}
```